# Wordpress specific page url doesn't return template

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and I created pages and template files for each page.
When I open any url, it shows me the template file associated with the url.
Except for the "blog" url, which seems not be recognised as a valid page and shows me the home page layout. If I rewrite the page url and page name for something else and adjust the statement in the functions.php to the new page's name, it works.
Well, I would like it to work for the "blog" as well.
What could be the problem? Any ideas are welcome.

```
if (isset($wp->query_vars["pagename"]) && $wp->query_vars["pagename"] == 'blog') {
    $templatefilename = 'layout-blog_layout.php';
    if (file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templatefilename)) {
        $return_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/layouts/' . $templatefilename;
    } else {
        $return_template = $plugindir . '/layouts/' . $templatefilename;
    }
    do_theme_redirect($return_template);
}
```

Comment: Is the blog/posts page setup as a static page in the Reading Settings of WordPress?  Use $query->is_home() if you want to check for the page you have setup as the blog/posts page.

Comment: The static page for the home page is the Front page and for the posts is the Blog page.

Comment: So, apparently I have a registered_post_type called "blog". Which I need to be displayed for posts, like "/blog/name-of-the-post"
On the other hand, I need the "/blog" url to be used as a page to be able to display the list of posts which are added by Advanced Custom Forms.
The only problem is, the "/blog" url is treated as a post_type and not as a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the problem was is that I have a registered_post_type as "blog", so it couldn't be used as a page. The pagename in the query_vars was not set for that url, so it couldn't have been recognised as a page. Instead I changed the statement to watch for the post_type=blog.

```
if (isset($wp->query_vars["post_type"]) && !isset($wp->query_vars["blog"]) && $wp->query_vars["post_type"] == 'blog') {
    $templatefilename = 'layout-blog_layout.php';
    if (file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templatefilename)) {
        $return_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/layouts/' . $templatefilename;
    } else {
        $return_template = $plugindir . '/layouts/' . $templatefilename;
    }
    do_theme_redirect($return_template);
}
```